# KafkaCat and Docker: Message too size

Tags: apache-kafka

We are running a Kafka cluster with the following configuration:

```
---
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - 32181:32181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
      - "localhost: 127.0.0.1"

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka-host
    ports:
      - 19092:19092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 22797510
      KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES: 22797510
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://docker.for.mac.host.internal:19092
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
      - "localhost: 127.0.0.1"

  kafka2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka-host2
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 22797510
      KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES: 22797510
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://docker.for.mac.host.internal:29092
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
      - "localhost: 127.0.0.1"

  kafka3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka-host2
    ports:
      - 39092:39092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 22797510
      KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES: 22797510
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://docker.for.mac.host.internal:39092
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
      - "localhost: 127.0.0.1"

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest
    hostname: sr-host
    ports:
      - 29081:29081
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:32181
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: sr-host
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://sr-host:29081
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
      - "localhost: 127.0.0.1"

  kafka-rest:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:latest
    hostname: kr-host
    ports:
      - 29080:29080
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: http://kr-host:29080
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://sr-host:29081
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: kr-host
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: docker.for.mac.host.internal:29092
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"
      - "localhost: 127.0.0.1"
```

And when we try to publish messages

```
kafkacat  -b docker.for.mac.host.internal:19092,docker.for.mac.host.internal:29092,docker.for.mac.host.internal:39092 -P -t cr -K, -l file.txt
```

but this get us an error

> % ERROR: Failed to produce message (2279751 bytes): Broker: Message size too large

Why does the broker ignore the value of KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES

Comment: Did you restart your Kafka cluster?

Comment: I did :( docker-compose down and docker-compose up

Comment: Have you tried copying `file.txt` inside the container?  `docker cp /path/t/file.txt CONTAINER_NAME:/`